# bg-url in tailwindcss is not working for me

Tags: background-image, tailwind-css

i get some problem that when i use **add to extend** / **use as arbitary values** ->> bg-url is not working

**\Arbirtary Values**

```
bg-[url('../../images/product/model-s.jpg')]
```

-- Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '../../images/product/model-s.jpg' in '....\MAIN PROJECT\0.PORTOFOLIO\tesla-clone\client\src' --

**\Extend**

```
backgroundImage: {"model-s": "url('./src/images/product/model-s.jpg')", },
```

-- Module not found: Error: Can't resolve './src/images/product/model-s.jpg' in ''....\MAIN PROJECT\0.PORTOFOLIO\tesla-clone\client\src' --

**### BUT.......**

when i **import it** i can use it as `<img />`

```
import models from "../../images/product/model-s.jpg";


<img src={models} alt="model S" className="w-full h-full object-cover bg-center bg-no-repeat"     />
```

Can you help me ? please....

Answer (score 1):

Here you have making the mistake while using the image in component. Since you already defined the image in `tailwind.config.js` like

```
.
.
extend: {
      backgroundImage: {
        'model_s': "url('./src/images/product/model-s.jpg')"
      }
}
.
.
```

You can simply use it like

```
<div className="bg-model_s" ></div>
```

> **Note** : I had change the name from `model-s` to `model_s`